# Move table in `book` class documents

Tags: tables, margins

I need to add some tables in `book` class document. At times the table is wider than the text. This is no problem when it happens on odd pages since they have bigger right margins and I will bind from the left as shown below.

[image]

However, it becomes a problem when the table has to be on even pages as show below because binding happens on the right side and part of the table will be affected. Hence, it would be better to let the extra table take space on the left hand side instead of the right on even pages. How to achieve this, please? Thank you! My example is attached below.

[image]

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, twoside, hidelinks, 11pt]{book}

  \usepackage{booktabs}
  \usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rccccc}
\toprule
Blah & Blah     & Blah & Blah     & Blah & Blah Blah Blah Blah \\ \midrule
-0.4    & -0.00495 & 0.02716  & 0.02719 & (0.70525, 1.34978) & (0.67622, 1.32378) \\
-0.3    & -0.00558 & 0.02534  & 0.02537 & (0.71227, 1.33488) & (0.68681, 1.31319) \\
-0.2    & -0.00616 & 0.02362  & 0.02366 & (0.71923, 1.32050) & (0.69718, 1.30282) \\
-0.1    & -0.00669 & 0.02201  & 0.02206 & (0.72613, 1.30662) & (0.70732, 1.29268) \\
0.1     & -0.00762 & 0.01909  & 0.01915 & (0.73968, 1.28034) & (0.72692, 1.27308) \\
0.2     & -0.00802 & 0.01776  & 0.01783 & (0.74636, 1.26790) & (0.73638, 1.26362) \\
0.3     & -0.00838 & 0.01652  & 0.01659 & (0.75294, 1.25591) & (0.74561, 1.25439) \\
0.4     & -0.00870 & 0.01536  & 0.01543 & (0.75945, 1.24439) & (0.75462, 1.24538) \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rccccc}
\toprule
Blah & Blah     & Blah & Blah     & Blah & Blah Blah Blah Blah \\ \midrule
-0.4    & -0.00495 & 0.02716  & 0.02719 & (0.70525, 1.34978) & (0.67622, 1.32378) \\
-0.3    & -0.00558 & 0.02534  & 0.02537 & (0.71227, 1.33488) & (0.68681, 1.31319) \\
-0.2    & -0.00616 & 0.02362  & 0.02366 & (0.71923, 1.32050) & (0.69718, 1.30282) \\
-0.1    & -0.00669 & 0.02201  & 0.02206 & (0.72613, 1.30662) & (0.70732, 1.29268) \\
0.1     & -0.00762 & 0.01909  & 0.01915 & (0.73968, 1.28034) & (0.72692, 1.27308) \\
0.2     & -0.00802 & 0.01776  & 0.01783 & (0.74636, 1.26790) & (0.73638, 1.26362) \\
0.3     & -0.00838 & 0.01652  & 0.01659 & (0.75294, 1.25591) & (0.74561, 1.25439) \\
0.4     & -0.00870 & 0.01536  & 0.01543 & (0.75945, 1.24439) & (0.75462, 1.24538) \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @touhami I don't see `\adjustwidth` in the question :-)

Comment: I'd say that a table that is too wide is a problem regardless. I'd try to reorganize the data to either not require wide tables (perhaps use other units, split the table into several, delete not-so-relevant columns, abbreviate headers and explain in the caption/surrounding text). Or, if nothing else works, typeset it sideways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. It's similar to @Werner answer, but I automate `tabular` align.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, hidelinks, 11pt]{book}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\mytabalign{%
    \edef\sk@align{\ifodd\c@page l\else r\fi}
    \makebox[\textwidth][\sk@align]}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\mytabalign{\begin{tabular}{rccccc}
\toprule
Blah & Blah     & Blah & Blah     & Blah & Blah Blah Blah Blah \\ \midrule
-0.4    & -0.00495 & 0.02716  & 0.02719 & (0.70525, 1.34978) & (0.67622, 1.32378) \\
-0.3    & -0.00558 & 0.02534  & 0.02537 & (0.71227, 1.33488) & (0.68681, 1.31319) \\
-0.2    & -0.00616 & 0.02362  & 0.02366 & (0.71923, 1.32050) & (0.69718, 1.30282) \\
-0.1    & -0.00669 & 0.02201  & 0.02206 & (0.72613, 1.30662) & (0.70732, 1.29268) \\
0.1     & -0.00762 & 0.01909  & 0.01915 & (0.73968, 1.28034) & (0.72692, 1.27308) \\
0.2     & -0.00802 & 0.01776  & 0.01783 & (0.74636, 1.26790) & (0.73638, 1.26362) \\
0.3     & -0.00838 & 0.01652  & 0.01659 & (0.75294, 1.25591) & (0.74561, 1.25439) \\
0.4     & -0.00870 & 0.01536  & 0.01543 & (0.75945, 1.24439) & (0.75462, 1.24538) \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{table}[h]
\centering

\mytabalign{\begin{tabular}{rccccc}
\toprule
Blah & Blah     & Blah & Blah     & Blah & Blah Blah Blah Blah \\ \midrule
-0.4    & -0.00495 & 0.02716  & 0.02719 & (0.70525, 1.34978) & (0.67622, 1.32378) \\
-0.3    & -0.00558 & 0.02534  & 0.02537 & (0.71227, 1.33488) & (0.68681, 1.31319) \\
-0.2    & -0.00616 & 0.02362  & 0.02366 & (0.71923, 1.32050) & (0.69718, 1.30282) \\
-0.1    & -0.00669 & 0.02201  & 0.02206 & (0.72613, 1.30662) & (0.70732, 1.29268) \\
0.1     & -0.00762 & 0.01909  & 0.01915 & (0.73968, 1.28034) & (0.72692, 1.27308) \\
0.2     & -0.00802 & 0.01776  & 0.01783 & (0.74636, 1.26790) & (0.73638, 1.26362) \\
0.3     & -0.00838 & 0.01652  & 0.01659 & (0.75294, 1.25591) & (0.74561, 1.25439) \\
0.4     & -0.00870 & 0.01536  & 0.01543 & (0.75945, 1.24439) & (0.75462, 1.24538) \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I'm not sure it work propely in all situation, but it seems work well in this case (inside `table` environment).

Comment: That is great. However, if I add `\caption{}`, the title will not be centered with respect to the table.

Comment: @LaTeXfan Of course. Caption content is aligned respect the textwidth, while the tabular width is greater than textwidth. If you want caption centered respect the table, you can define `\newcommand*\mytabalign{\makebox[\textwidth][c]}` instead of my previous definition.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest compiling your `book` and wait to adjust such things right at the very end. At that time you can avoid overfull `\hbox` warnings for oversized odd-page `tabular`s using

```
\makebox[0pt][l]{\begin{tabular}{..}
  ...
\end{tabular}}
```

and even-page `tabular`s using

```
\raggedleft
\makebox[0pt][r]{\begin{tabular}{..}
  ...
\end{tabular}}
```

Here is your example in action:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{book}

\usepackage{booktabs,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \begin{tabular}{rccccc}
      \toprule
      Blah & Blah     & Blah & Blah     & Blah & Blah Blah Blah Blah \\ \midrule
      -0.4    & -0.00495 & 0.02716  & 0.02719 & (0.70525, 1.34978) & (0.67622, 1.32378) \\
      -0.3    & -0.00558 & 0.02534  & 0.02537 & (0.71227, 1.33488) & (0.68681, 1.31319) \\
      -0.2    & -0.00616 & 0.02362  & 0.02366 & (0.71923, 1.32050) & (0.69718, 1.30282) \\
      -0.1    & -0.00669 & 0.02201  & 0.02206 & (0.72613, 1.30662) & (0.70732, 1.29268) \\
      0.1     & -0.00762 & 0.01909  & 0.01915 & (0.73968, 1.28034) & (0.72692, 1.27308) \\
      0.2     & -0.00802 & 0.01776  & 0.01783 & (0.74636, 1.26790) & (0.73638, 1.26362) \\
      0.3     & -0.00838 & 0.01652  & 0.01659 & (0.75294, 1.25591) & (0.74561, 1.25439) \\
      0.4     & -0.00870 & 0.01536  & 0.01543 & (0.75945, 1.24439) & (0.75462, 1.24538) \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{table}[h]
  \raggedleft
  \makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \begin{tabular}{rccccc}
      \toprule
      Blah & Blah     & Blah & Blah     & Blah & Blah Blah Blah Blah \\ \midrule
      -0.4    & -0.00495 & 0.02716  & 0.02719 & (0.70525, 1.34978) & (0.67622, 1.32378) \\
      -0.3    & -0.00558 & 0.02534  & 0.02537 & (0.71227, 1.33488) & (0.68681, 1.31319) \\
      -0.2    & -0.00616 & 0.02362  & 0.02366 & (0.71923, 1.32050) & (0.69718, 1.30282) \\
      -0.1    & -0.00669 & 0.02201  & 0.02206 & (0.72613, 1.30662) & (0.70732, 1.29268) \\
      0.1     & -0.00762 & 0.01909  & 0.01915 & (0.73968, 1.28034) & (0.72692, 1.27308) \\
      0.2     & -0.00802 & 0.01776  & 0.01783 & (0.74636, 1.26790) & (0.73638, 1.26362) \\
      0.3     & -0.00838 & 0.01652  & 0.01659 & (0.75294, 1.25591) & (0.74561, 1.25439) \\
      0.4     & -0.00870 & 0.01536  & 0.01543 & (0.75945, 1.24439) & (0.75462, 1.24538) \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Automation of this procedure may indeed be possible, but it heavily depends on your typical use of `tabular` (inside floats and/or outside, for example).

Comment: That is great. However, if I add `\caption{}`, the title will not be centered with respect to the table. Is there a way to fix that, please?

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is your table being too large and this happens, because there is too much data in it for the text width you have :) As a consequence, I see different possibilities to resolve the issue:

1. Change the formatting of your table. You could, for example, display the pairs on two lines instead of using `(... , ...)`. Or write `.123` instead of `0.123`, depending on the conventions used in your domain. Another way would be to use different scaling units, e.g. `2.716` instead of `0.02716` with the factor `$10^{-2}$` written in the column title. Again, this can or cannot be feasible.
2. Use `\small` font size. This *will* make your table smaller. However, it can become more difficult to read, depending on the actual content you have.
3. Use the float environment `table`, put the table on a separate page and have it typeset in landscape format.

If none of these possibilities (or combinations thereof) work for you, you might try to force LaTeX to have the table protrude into the *outer* margin instead of the right margin. While writing this, I can see Werner already showed you how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on `tabularx`, and playing with `\arraycolsep` shows the table can be exactly textwidth wide. I added the `siunitx` package to format the numbers in the first four columns.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{book}

\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx, siunitx, lipsum}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}m{#1}<{$}}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[h]\setlength\extrarowheight{1.5pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{\,}S[table-format=-1.1]S[table-format=-1.5]S[table-format=1.5]S[table-format=1.5]XX @{\,}}
    \toprule
    {Blah} & Blah & Blah & Blah & \text{Blah} & \parbox{\hsize}{\centering Blah Blah Blah Blah} \\[1ex]
    \midrule
    -0.4 & -0.00495 & 0.02716 & 0.02719 & (0.70525, 1.34978) & (0.67622, 1.32378) \\
    -0.3 & -0.00558 & 0.02534 & 0.02537 & (0.71227, 1.33488) & (0.68681, 1.31319) \\
    -0.2 & -0.00616 & 0.02362 & 0.02366 & (0.71923, 1.32050) & (0.69718, 1.30282) \\
    -0.1 & -0.00669 & 0.02201 & 0.02206 & (0.72613, 1.30662) & (0.70732, 1.29268) \\
    0.1 & -0.00762 & 0.01909 & 0.01915 & (0.73968, 1.28034) & (0.72692, 1.27308) \\
    0.2 & -0.00802 & 0.01776 & 0.01783 & (0.74636, 1.26790) & (0.73638, 1.26362) \\
    0.3 & -0.00838 & 0.01652 & 0.01659 & (0.75294, 1.25591) & (0.74561, 1.25439) \\
    0.4 & -0.00870 & 0.01536 & 0.01543 & (0.75945, 1.24439) & (0.75462, 1.24538) \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]